# Is it OK to accept an answer to community-wiki question?

Tags: support, community-wiki

Please, state the official SO policy! Don't give me link to another question where this has been discussed to death without any conclusion at the end.

P.S. Should I accept some answer to this question? ;)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As the question owner, it is your right to show what you consider the right or your favorite answer (as often is the case with CW questions, there isn't a "right" answer per se).

Answer (score 9):

> Don't give me link to another question where this has been discussed to death without any conclusion at the end.

What? This is meta! It is what we do here!

Answer (score 6):

Yes :D All you're doing is communicating the answer that helped you most, all the other answers are still visible and otehr users can decide for themselves. Plus with all this "accept answer rate" going around, I hope they mean for us to accept answer to CW questions too

Comment: CW questions are explicitly excluded from the accepted answer rate calculation -- precisely because CW questions may be such that you cannot accept a single, right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why it wouldn't be.

For an example, in the FAQ, if one post becomes the all encompassing "canonical" source for the answer, then I don't see why marking it as the accepted would be unacceptable.

Answer (score -1):

The system alows you to do it, then it all comes down to deciding yoursef if a particular wiki question should have and anwer marked as accepted or not, depending entirely on the nature of the quetion and the answers.